# Apache2 SSL certificate error

Tags: apache, ssl

I am trying to add SSL certificates from Comodo Security Services on Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) OpenSSL/1.0.1k server.

For configuration:

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/24-06-2016/private.key
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/24-06-2016/account_veedo_ru_2017_06_24.crt
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/24-06-2016/intermediate.crt
```

I've got error after Apache2 restart:

```
[Thu Jun 30 07:39:20.895631 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 4614] AH02561: Failed to configure certificate account.veedo.ru:443:0, check /etc/ssl/24-06-2016/account_veedo_ru_2017_06_24.crt
[Thu Jun 30 07:39:20.895688 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 4614] SSL Library Error: error:140AD009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file:PEM lib
AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

For configuration:

```
SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/ssl/24-06-2016/private.key
SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/24-06-2016/account_veedo_ru_2017_06_24.crt
SSLCACertificateFile        /etc/ssl/24-06-2016/intermediate.crt
```

The error is:

```
[Thu Jul 07 18:22:21.423776 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 14180] AH02562: Failed to configure certificate account.veedo.ru:443:0 (with chain), check /etc/ssl/24-06-2016/account_veedo_ru_2017_06_24.crt
[Thu Jul 07 18:22:21.423826 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 14180] SSL Library Error: error:140DC009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file:PEM lib
AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

What is wrong? How can I check my certificates? Please help!

Comment: You can check that certificates  and keys are in PEM format (headers `----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----` and `----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----`)and they are not corrupt   `openssl rsa -in privateKey.key -check` and `openssl x509 -in certificate.crt -text -noout`

Comment: You should use the first configuration. The second is for client authentication

Answer (score 1):

Seller wrote me that there was an extra line feed symbol in certificate. It is fixed now and works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

there is a line at the end of crt file that should be removed , just before ---- end ...
really annoying